# How to replace words with hyperlink in specific index using Jquery expression?

Tags: jquery, regex, javascript-framework

I replace "#" tag with link by using below function,

```
$('.content').each(function(index) {
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(#\w+)/g, "<a target='_self' class='msg_links' href='http://test.com/search/q=$1'>$1</a>"));
 });
```

Suppose string is like this :

```
"Hello how are you #frineds, whats going on?"
```

**It retruns like this :**

```
"Hello how are you <a href='http://test.com/search/q=#frineds'>#frineds</a>, whats going on?"
```

**Instead of I want to like this**

```
"Hello how are you  <a href='http://test.com/search/q=%23frineds'>#frineds</a>, whats going on? "
```

How I can do this using Jquery?

-Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to use `encodeURIComponent` on the matched string:

```
 $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(#\w+)/g, function($0, $1) {
     return "<a target='_self' class='msg_links' href='http://test.com/search/q=" + encodeURIComponent($1) + "'>" + $1 + "</a>");
 });
```

Or exclude the `#` from the match and make the `%23` hard coded:

```
 $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a target='_self' class='msg_links' href='http://test.com/search/q=%23$1'>$1</a>"));
```